# LESS CSS - &:focus not working in variable selector

Tags: html, css, less

I have the following code in my `.less` stylesheet.

```
@text-inputs: input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email], input[type=number];
@shade: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

.highlight {
    background: @shade;
}

.input-highlight {
    @{text-inputs} {
        .highlight;
    }
}

.input-highlight-subtle {
    @{text-inputs} {
        &:focus {
            .highlight;
        }
    }
}
```

My HTML:

```
<body class="input-highlight-subtle">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type Here" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Type Here"/>    
</body>
```

The result of the above CSS: The background of the input is the `@shade` color even when I'm not hovering on the input. I checked in my browser developer tools and apparently it generates the code like this:

```
.highlight {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.input-highlight-subtle input[type=text], input[type=password],  input[type=email], input[type=number]:focus {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

So how do I solve this?

EDIT:

Basically I'd like to have an output like this:

```
.input-highlight-subtle input[type="text"]:focus, .input-highlight-subtle input[type="password"]:focus, .input-highlight-subtle  input[type="email"]:focus, .input-highlight-subtle input[type="number"]:focus {
    .highlight;
}
```

How can I achieve that ^ with LESS code? (Pun Intended)

Comment: Why would you want a hover effect on an input? Maybe focus is a better choice?

Comment: That's clearly a bug in LESS so it is better to send bug report to LESS team.

Comment: That doesn't make sens. Your SCSS has `hover`, and the resulting CSS has `focus`. Either this is a bizarre bug, or (more likely) you are looking at an old version of the output of the SCSS. Maybe it is cached?

Comment: @GolezTrol Whoops. My bad, that was a typo. I've edited it now.

Comment: You know you can use Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V to prevent typos like that, right? ;)

Comment: @GolezTrol I did. But I edited and ran it again in between, hence the different result. :P By typo, I meant just a general mistake. :) So yes that was a newer output.

Comment: Ok clear. Well. It *might* be a bug in SCSS. The value of `@text-inputs` is inserted as-is. SCSS doesn't seem to parse them anymore to mix in `:focus`. It probably depends on the order in which they are evaluated, but I'm not sure whether this is a bug or by design.

Comment: `&` won't work with a selector *list* in a variable because the interpolated variable is assumed to represent a single selector element and never a list. For possible solutions see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407388/multiple-nested-selectors-with-variables-in-less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
.text-inputs() {
    input[type=text], input[type=password],input[type=email], input[type=number]{        
        .text-inputs-properties();
    }
}

@shade: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

.highlight {
    background: @shade;
}

.input-highlight {
    .text-inputs();
    .text-inputs-properties() {       
        .highlight;
    }  
}

.input-highlight-subtle {
    .text-inputs();
    .text-inputs-properties() {
        &:hover{
            .highlight;
        }
    }      
}
```

Credits for @seven-phases-max for his answer [Focused selector in variable . How to do that stuff in LESS like in SCSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780648/focused-selector-in-variable-how-to-do-that-stuff-in-less-like-in-scss)

I have just adapted it to your case, Here you have it working on this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/90y6n103/) example, I hope this helps

**EDIT1:** I found [this @scottgit comment](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1421) and I thought it should also be considered

" there is a work around to get the functionality of assigning properties to a set of selectors defined in a variable using the capabilities of LESS 1.7. Consider this:"

```
//I modified the code a litter bit for your case   

@shade: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

@inputs: {input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=password], input[type=number] {.getProps()}};
@pseudo: ~':hover';
@props: { background: @shade;};

.input-highlight-subtle{
    .setProps(@selectors; @props; @extension: ~'') {
        @selectors();
        .getProps() {
            &@{extension} { @props(); }
        }
    } 

    .setProps(@inputs; @props; @pseudo);
}
```

"So I can assign a pseudo class if I want or not, and pass a set of properties as needed. The key is to put the mixin `.getProps()` call into the block that is defining the selectors for variable `@inputs`, which is then called as a local mixin inside `.setProps()` so that the properties get put where we want them. The `@extension` could be any escaped string to add to each selector as an additional part of the selector string. Above I do `:focus` as a pseudo class, but I could have done `~' > div + div'` as a child and sibling combination, or whatever."

and [here the jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/hb2rsm2x/108/)

Comment: Thanks! I checked out @seven-phases-max answer, and yes it is similar to my issue. However, I did not quite understand how to adopt the solution in my case of pseudo-selectors. You helped me with that. :)

Comment: @ADeveloper  I'm Glad to help u, I found another way and I thought it should also be considered